# Form Element Decorators

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-decorators

I have been trying to create a custom form with Zend_Form and Decorators, the desired html formatting is as follows:

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post" action="">
    <div class="login_bx">
        <div id="txtAccount-label" class="txt_field">
            <label for="txtAccount" class="required">Account ID:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="inp_field">
            <input type="text" name="txtAccount" id="txtAccount" value="" style="width:250px">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

the contents of Zend_Form class are as follows:

```
$account    =   new Zend_Form_Element_Text('txtAccount');
        $account    ->  setLabel('Account ID:')
                    ->  setAttrib('style','width:250px')
                    ->  setRequired(true)
                    ->  addValidator('NotEmpty', true);

        $this->setDecorators(array(
            'FormElements',
            array(
                'HtmlTag', 
                array(
                    'tag'   =>  'div',
                    'class' =>  'login_bx',
                )
            ),
            'Form',
            array('FormErrors', array(
                'placement'                 =>  'prepend', 
                'markupElementLabelEnd'     =>  '</strong>', 
                'markupElementLabelStart'   =>  '<strong>', 
                'markupListStart'           =>  '<div class="errors_list" id="msg">', 
                'markupListEnd'             =>  '</div>', 
                'markupListItemStart'       =>  '<div class="error_item">', 
                'markupListItemEnd'         =>  '</div>'
            ))
        ));

        $this->addElements(array($account));

        $this->setElementDecorators(array(
            'ViewHelper',
            //'Errors',
            array(array(
                'data' => 'HtmlTag'
                ), array(
                    'tag'   =>  'div',
                    'class' =>  'inp_field'
                )
            ),
            array('Label', array(
                'tag'   =>  'div',
                'class' =>  'txt_field'
            ))
        ));
```

the current html rendered is as follows:

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post" action="">
    <div class="login_bx">
        <div id="txtAccount-label">
            <label for="txtAccount" class="txt_field required">Account ID:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="inp_field">
            <input type="text" name="txtAccount" id="txtAccount" value="" style="width:250px">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I couldn't figure out how to add class to the DIV wrapping the label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
array('Label', array(
                'tag'   =>  'div',
                'class' =>  'txt_field'
            ))
```

**use**

```
array('Label', array(
                'tag'   =>  'div',
                'tagClass' =>  'txt_field'
            ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$name = new Zend_From_Element_Text("txtName");
$name->setOptions(array('class'=>'css class name'));
```

http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=69&t=1367

or this

[how to add special class for labels and errors on zend form elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595000/how-to-add-special-class-for-labels-and-errors-on-zend-form-elements)

Comment: My question here have been misunderstood, I am using Zend Decorators to replace the default layout OL-LI layout, with div's.
The solution suggested by you, would add the said class to the element itself and not to the div wrapping the label tag.